# ExtJs getCmp failure

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have this code to check the if the form is already there. But it gives an error.

```
onRender : function() {
    var cmp = Ext.getCmp('myForm');
    if (cmp) {
        alert("Component of this type already exist");
        return;
    }
```

Error comes from ExtJs core. In debugger, it bombs at the call `Ext.getCmp()`;

Comment: What is the error?  Is it in the js console, or by "gives an error" do you mean the if(cmp) evaluates to true?

Answer (score 1):

re you sure you're using ExtJS (source file `ext-all.js`) and not Ext Core (source file `ext-core.js`)?

`Ext.getCmp()` is part of ExtJS library, and is not present in Ext Core.

Comment: I don't know the exact lib, it is from inside Ext.

Answer (score 0):

is your app working fine other that this?

Check all your includes, you should include an adapter before ext-all.js